# reducing light reflection on a wall

Tags: walls, light

I have a wall across from the doorways of a bedroom and "office."  It reflects light into the bedroom which bothers people trying to sleep with the other door open.  What would be a good way to reduce the light reflection?  Ideally we could keep both the doors open to hear each other if needed and also for airflow and pet traffic.  Also light in the office is needed for hobby work so simply turning the light off isn't always the best solution, either.  Preferably some kind of wall hanging would be what I'm thinking of.

Comment: put up some mirrors ... they can actually make the wall look dark because they do not scatter light in the same way as a wall

Comment: @jsotola wouldn't that just reflect more of the light into the other room?  I do happen to already have an extra mirror I can set up and test this out, so I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hang black felt - it eats light quite effectively. You want to make sure that it's fire-treated, or apply a fire treatment yourself, since "things like curtains" (which it would be) are a big problem in spreading fire fast - if not treated to prevent/reduce that issue. Other black (or dark colored) fabrics may work, but the surface on felt is particularly effective at being non-reflective.

You could also apply a flat black/dark paint, but that might not be a viable option (did not specify, but you were asking about "preferably a wall hanging.")

Depending on what the lighting in the office is, and the nature of the hobby work, using directed task lighting rather than a general overhead light may also help reduce light bleed.

Answer (score 3):

It might not help with air flow, but hanging a lined door curtain over the inside of the office door will stop the light escaping the office, and you will still hear what is going on in the bedroom.

Answer (score 1):

An option which might take a little work is to reverse the hinges on one or both doors so there is no direct visual path from the bed to the wall area illuminated from the office.